# How to load multiple apps in one domain in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to load two apps in one domain based on own roles. 
There are two methods for implementing this:-

1. Create a project and create children's module of app module by the [asynchronous-routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#!#asynchronous-routing) method.
2. Create a project and create different two apps like first is the app and second is app1 and load by role based.

I am using angular-CLI of my project. In my project 500+ components. So which one is better and How to implement it?

Comment: How are you serving your application?

Comment: @Harleen did you found any success ??

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed yes I found it, I have create a two different app and upload these apps under the FTP sub-directory. Link this: www.test.com/admin, www.test.com/customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run each app on it's own site.

```
http://localhost:4000/
http://localhost:4001/
```

Then use a gateway server to redirect based on part of the url:

```
http://localhost:80/admin ====> site1
http://localhost:80/public ====> site2
```

Comment: and rememeber to set up CORS accordingly.